# Clip Tool with PyQGIS give error

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I've got the following Code for cutting points by a mask layer:

```
pointlayer = 'C:/temp/points.shp'
masklayer = 'C:/temp/mask.shp'
outputlayer = 'C:/temp/result.shp'

algo = 'native:clip'
params = {
'INPUT' : pointlayer,
'OUTPUT' : outputlayer,
'OVERLAY' : masklayer
}

import processing
processing.runAndLoadResults(algo, params)
```

It throws me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 13, in <module>
  File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 151, in runAndLoadResults
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(alg, parameters=parameters, onFinish=handleAlgorithmResults, feedback=feedback,
  File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 189, in runAlgorithm
    ret, results = execute(alg, parameters, context, feedback, catch_exceptions=False)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\gui\AlgorithmExecutor.py", line 71, in execute
    results, ok = alg.run(parameters, context, feedback, {}, False)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Konnte Obekt nicht in OUTPUT schreiben
```

But if I change the output to a `'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'` it works. Can someone explain why and how to fix this? I need the result in a not-temporary file.

With just `processing.run(algo, params)` I got the same error!

Comment: What does the error say in English?

Comment: Its like: Couldnt write object to output

Comment: Does "result.shp" already exist?

Comment: No, it does not exist. But it is created when i run the script. But it does not have any features in it.

Comment: did you try change the result filename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution with just using another algorithm: `saga:clippointswithpolygons`

With this algorithm i can store the output without problems.